# parse query parameters from request in rust

Tags: rust

I'm using rust for the first time and i'm trying to parse query parameters from a http request. Lets say the request url is `http://someUrl.com?param1=123&param2=345`
I'm trying to capture 123 and 345

Comment: What crate are you using for making (or handling) the request?

Comment: @PeterHall im not sure what crate to use. any recommendations?

Comment: Is this a real http request coming in? Surely you're using some crate to host the server or receive the request. That library will be parsing the url for you.

Comment: I agree with @SilvioMayolo. This question needs more context. URLs don't materialize out of thin air, it has to come from somewhere. Where do you get the URL from?

Answer (score 3):

If you are handling a request in a web server, the web server crate that you are using will certainly have its own way to do this.

If you just need to parse query parameters from a URL, you can do that using [`url`](https://docs.rs/url/latest/url/):

```
use url::Url; // v2.3.1

fn main() {
    let url = Url::try_from("http://someUrl.com?param1=123&param2=345").unwrap();

    for (key, val) in url.query_pairs() {
        println!("{key} = {val}");
    }
}
```

Here the variables are all strings.

More likely, you'll want to deserialize the variables into convenient types. You can do that with [`serde`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/) and [`serde_qs`](https://docs.rs/serde_qs/latest/serde_qs/):

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use url::Url;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MyQuery {
    param1: usize,
    param2: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let url = Url::try_from("http://someUrl.com?param1=123&param2=345").unwrap();

    if let Some(query) = url.query() {
        let my_query: MyQuery = serde_qs::from_str(query).unwrap();

        println!("{my_query:?}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the serde_qs hint, this worked super well!